# Stop recycling in R

Tags: r, coercion

In order to better understand R, I'm working on a toy example. In particular, I'm trying to force R not to perform recycling so that an error is produced while summing

```
(1:2) + 1.
```

I tried:

```
1:2 + I(1)
```

then, just to check since it seems related, I tried

```
"+"(1, I(TRUE))
```

but that works fine too, suggesting to me that the class is unrelated to the coercion and perhaps the recycling. I couldn't figure out where/how the length of an atomic vector is stored, either.

Do you perhaps know of some way to keep this recycling from happening? From what I understand, R does all of its recycling/coercion before its internal C code runs, but I can't figure out where that's happening to stop it.

Comment: What you call "length coercion" is more typically referred to as "recycling" (as you do in your first sentence). Vector recycling is very deeply baked into R: I don't think it will be easy (possible?) to prevent it.

Comment: You could write your own function that checks lengths. Or convert to matrix

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for info! Is it still sensible to refer to recycling as length-coercion?

Comment: @Dason Thank you for the tip! I'm trying to use this example as a tool to better understand coercion and recycling. I'll edit the question to make this more clear

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with "length coercion" except that it's unfamiliar (did you make up the term yourself or did you get it from somewhere?); if you want to communicate with R people, calling it "recycling" will probably work better

Comment: @BenBolker Okay! I just made up the term. I've edited the question to remove references to length-coercion in favor of recycling, and refocused it particularly on recycling.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to forbid recycling with arithmetic operators :

```r
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:6
z <-  7:10 # length 4!

# give them an S3 class
class(x) <- class(y) <- class(z) <- "foo"

# define a group generic method for operators (see ?groupGeneric)
Ops.foo <- function(e1, e2) {
  if(length(e1) != length(e2)){
    stop("no recycling!")
  }
  NextMethod(.Generic)
}

x + y
#> [1] 5 7 9
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "foo"
x + z
#> Error in Ops.foo(x, z): no recycling!
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

with functions like `cbind()` I think you're out of luck though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop recycling in R. But lucky for you, recycling is only for atomic vectors as far as I know. So work with matrices!

```
matrix(1:2,ncol=1) + matrix(1,ncol=1,nrow=1)
```

will throw a dimension not comparable error :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It seems like running

vec <- 1:2;
vec2 <- 1;

attr(vec, "dim") <- 2;
attr(vec2, "dim") <- 1;

vec + vec2

forces similar behavior for vectors. I guess since the "dim" attribute is what makes the problem for coercion, and this forces the atomic vectors into being arrays, where I suppose there's similar behavior as matrices.

Comment: @user163964 Thank you for that insight! Good to learn that :)