# strange result in vector comparison

Tags: r

I  am a beginner just with 2 weeks experience.

my current system is R 4.1.2 windows on WIN11

when I run below code,

```
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
z <- c(1, 4)
y == z
```

The output is TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE, which is quite acceptable.

However, when I changed the vector y sequence to

```
y <- c(2, 1, 3, 4) 
z <- c(1, 4) 
y == z
```

Then, surprisingly, the output is FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE, while, I supporsed the result would be TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE.

What's wrong with me? can any one help me to explain the scheme of the vector comparison and  why I have above result?

Comment: The “==“ is a pairwise comparison between the left and right side. In this case the right side with 2 elements is recycled to make both sides equal length.  If Z had 3 elements, you would have received an error.  To compare 2 lists the %in% function is handy.

Comment: thank you for the reply, which help me to understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z` gets [recycled](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#scalars-and-recycling-rules) - meaning you are comparing `c(2,1,3,4)` to `c(1,4,1,4)` which is `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`.

There are some caeveats when relying on vectors to be recycled. Base R will usually return output of length of the longest vector, and toss a warning when it is not able to convert.

```
data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(1,2,3, 4))
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 1 3
4 2 4
# but
data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(1,2,3))
#> Error in data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c(1, 2, 3)) : 
  #> arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

To create a more intuitive understanding, have a look at the results of

```
1:10 + 1:2
1:9 + 1:2
(1:10)[c(T,F)]
```

In some package you may expect different behavior. For example, the [vctrs](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/vec_recycle.html) package defined the following recycling rules:

[image]

This has implications for when you use the `tidyverse`, for example:

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(1,2))
```

Throws an error, as tibbles will only recycle vectors of length one.

In the rare case that you don't want recycling to happen, see [Moody_Mudskippers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465485/stop-recycling-in-r) answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your example the smaller vector is being 'recycled' and this is leading to your "strange" result, i.e.

```r
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
z <- c(1, 4)
y == z
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

y <- c(2, 1, 3, 4) 
z <- c(1, 4) 
y == z
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

When the smaller vector is 'manually' recycled you get the same result:

```r
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
z <- c(1, 4, 1, 4)
y == z
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

y <- c(2, 1, 3, 4) 
z <- c(1, 4, 1, 4) 
y == z
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I suspect you are looking for the `%in%` value matching operator (i.e. for each number in the vector "y", does it exist in "z"?):

```
y <- c(2, 1, 3, 4) 
z <- c(1, 4) 
y %in% z
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, which does help me to understand the problem thoroughtly.